# Standard Orders object on Community Builder

Tags: community, community-builder, napili, order

Any idea how can I expose the Orders tab from Community Builder Napili Template?

I've got orders enabled, but I cannot find it from the list of objects when I'm adding a new Menu Item on the Navigation Menu component.

[image: Navigation Menu Edit Screenshot]

According to [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_template_feature_comparison_table.htm&language=en_US), Orders are available on Napili template, do I need to set something up first before the orders can be exposed?

**UPDATE 23/02/**
Ok I've tried @tobibeers comment and thought that it works. Yes, you can create a community object page using orders but it throws weird errors when trying to navigate through them.

Here's what i've done:
1. Create object page based on Order object.

**Order Detail**
[image: OrderDetail]

**Order List**
[image: OrderList]

2. On the Navigation Menu component, add a Menu Item as a Community Page, then use the Order List page that was created. I've replaced the object and filterId parameter with "Order" and an order list view id respectively. Saved successfully.
   [image: OrderNav]
3. Tried navigating to the orders tab. It shows the order list view that I've specified but a weird error pops up. 
   [image: TabErr]
4. Then I closed the pop-up, tried clicking on one of the order records from the list view. And this error comes up.
   [image: OrderErr]

Thought that creating that object page works, am I still missing something?

Comment: No idea what your problem is, but for me Orders are listed just fine.

Comment: Hey @tobibeer are you using the community builder with Napili template?

Comment: At least that's what I just tried in a dev org using the napili template. I went to > Setup > Customize > Communities > All Communities > Builder (link for the community) < ...and then clicked on > Pages Manager (left controls) > + (button) > Create Object Page < ...see http://imgur.com/COxZcHp

Comment: I've updated my post based on your suggestion. Creating the page works, but it has thrown weird errors around when trying to navigate through  the orders page.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue and it seems that the orders object is not supported in the Napili template

[image: Supported Objects in Napili]

This is mentioned in their Spring '16 release guides - https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf

Comment: Shucks, need to read the release notes more. Thanks for this!