# Show Content Records in Napili Community

Tags: community, tab, napili

How do i make salesforce content visible via Community Builder ?

Answer (score 2):

The closest you will get OOB is Files Component .In my spring 17 org the component looks like below

[image]

The Libraries is read only and if you share a library with your customer community user the files will appear under library .

There is no way to publish a content currently .However since objects are exposed you can build a custom component .Please note I am using spring 17 org for screenshot .

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell me how can I see all content records in community, I am using Napili Templates and there is no option for Content

Comment: You will need to build it via a custom lightning component .The records will be there in content version object .Use a query to pull

Comment: Okay, It means there is no way to see directly. I am able to see some object in list(Case, Account, Contact). But dont know why Content  is not

Comment: Yes .Thats correct .Content is not available OOB except via libraries .Hope that helps .Thanks

Comment: Thanks Mohith, What about Question, Question & Answer, Knowledge Objects Records. Documentation Mentioned that these all are available   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111216/standard-orders-object-on-community-builder

Comment: Yes those have there own components from the component builder .Not necessarily they are available as tabs but they have there components .Example Question and answer is ASK A QUESTION  button and similarly knowledge has its own OOB components

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_template_feature_comparison_table.htm&language=en_US&type=0 They mentioned all are available except Content